# Samba server permission

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, services

I would like to know how can I enable this option to ask every time user name and password when user is tried to access share folder from Linux machine.

For instance I have setup a shared folder on Ubuntu and I access from windows machine at first time it asks user name and password but 2nd time when I try to access this folder it doesn't ask credentials and pop up a share screen folder.

I would like to do that when ever use tries to access any folder from Ubuntu machine they are promoted for user name and password and can't get share screen with out supplying credentials.

I have practiced and observed from windows 7 and windows 10 machine by accessing share folder on Ubuntu .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It actually is asking for credentials and Windows is supplying them each time it accesses the share but it is done without user intervention. It's a Windows thing.

When you first accessed the share from Windows you were asked for credentials. When Windows successfully gained access it will "remember forever" those credentials. The next time it accesses the share it will be asked and supply those remembered credentials in the background.

You can prove this to yourself if you are interested. Disable the Windows credentials from the samba password database:

```
sudo smbpasswd -d windows-user-name
```

At the next session when you try to access the share access will be denied because the "remembered" credentials on the Windows system no longer exists on the Linux system.

To restore the credentials:

```
sudo smbpassed -e windows-user-name
```